# Create a vector from another selecting some of its values at random but in order and with a minimum distance between selected ones?

Tags: r, vector, random, sequence

I have a vector of numbers and I would like to select some of them at random but in order. How could I do it?

For example:

```
vector <- runif(10, min=0, max=101)
vector 

  [1] 35.956732 67.608039 20.099881 23.184217  9.157408 34.105185 97.459770 25.805254 74.537667 18.865662
```

Which code can I use to create a new vector containing, for example, four out of the 10 values with the requirement that those four values are in the same order than the original vector? That is, the vector can not be `9.157408 67.608039 74.537667 97.459770` but `67.608039 9.157408 97.459770 74.537667`.

Any help would be great. Thanks in advance.

### Second part (updated)

What if I want a certain number of steps among consecutive selected values?

That is, if I have for instance this vector:

[1] 2.1  3.4  1.6  8.9  2.3  5.4  6.4  1.3  10.8  3.7  13.4  2.4  5.4  6.8

How can I select 3 out of that 14 values with the additional condition that there has to be at least 3 non-selected values between two selected ones. For example, a selected vector could be `2.1  5.4  6.8` but it couldn't be `1.6  5.4  10.8`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can `sample` 4 elements from the `vector`, then `match` to get the index and subset the `vector`

```
v1 <- sample(vector, 4)
vector[match(v1, vector)]
```

---

If we need to `sample` 1 element every 4, we could use `rollapply` by specifying the `width` and `by`

```
library(zoo)
rollapply(v2, 4, by = 4, FUN = function(x) sample(x, 1))
#[1] 1.6 1.3 2.4
```

---

Or use a loop

```
out <- c()
flag <- TRUE
i <- 1
while(flag) {
    if((i + 4) > length(v2)) {
    break
      flag <- FALSE
      
    }
    
    i1 <- i:(i + 2)
    
    tmp <- sample(i1, 1)
    out <- c(out, tmp)

    i <- tmp + 3
    

}

out
#[1]  3  7 11
```

#### data

```
v2 <- c(2.1, 3.4, 1.6, 8.9, 2.3, 5.4, 6.4, 1.3, 10.8, 3.7, 13.4, 2.4, 
5.4, 6.8)
```

Comment: Thanks @akrun. As I have said to ThomaslsCoding, I forgot to include an extra condition for creating the vector. I apologize. I have just included it. Do you know how to create the vector considering also that I do not want to select values very close to each other?

Comment: @Dekike If the first element sampled is at position 12, do you discard it or go backwards

Comment: Good question. Then there should be another condition that is that the first value selected is not further than 3 positions (for instance) from the beginning. Do you understand? My real case is data for an animal over time. Since the temporal autocorrelation in data is high, I want to select a part of the original data (that's why I need data in order).

Comment: @Dekike Try the updated code with `rollapply`.  I guess it should work

Comment: @Dekike It is rolling with step 4 at a time while selecting 4 elements

Comment: Thanks!! I saw it! One doubt, if I do not want a specific width? I mean, I want to select one value at least every certain steps (e.g., 4) but I want to select as much values as I can. I have seen that I have to specify the `width` argument.

Comment: @Dekike you could use a `for` loop to make it more robust though

Comment: @Dekike Suppose, if the element selected is at position 2, then in the next step, is it starting from 6 to 8 and sample one element i.e. 8 and so on?

Comment: Sorry @akrun, why if I use a width of 1 I get rare results? For instance, I create the vector `v2 <- c(1:16)`, and then I run `rollapply(v2, 1, by = 2, FUN = function(x) sample(x, 1))`, and I got the vector `[1] 1 2 4 3 7 3 9 2`, which does not follow any order and has repeated values. Is it suppose that `width` indicates the number of elements? Why if I indicate `1` I get 8 elements and they are not ordered? It is just to understand the logical behind this.

Comment: Just look at the values it is selecitng when `width = 1`, i.e. `rollapply(v2, 1, by = 2, FUN = I)#[1]  2.1  1.6  2.3  6.4 10.8 13.4  5.4` i.e. it selects 1 value every 2 steps

Comment: What I want is just to select  (randomly) certain values from `v2`, but I do not want repeated values and I want a certain distance between selected values. For instance, in the vector `v2 <- c(1:16)`, I would like to randomly select some of those values with the condition that the distance between two consecutive selected values is at least 2. That is, I can't have `3` and `4` selected. I would expect something like this: `2  6  9  11  14  16`.

Comment: I understand, but my doubt is why if `v2` is `v2 <- c(1:16)`, if I run `rollapply(v2, 1, by = 2, FUN = function(x) sample(x, 1))`, I get `[1] 1 3 2 3 9 4 8 1`. This does not have any sense for mee.

Comment: @Dekike You may check the `getAnywhere("rollapply.zoo") which is called by `"rollapply.default"`. It may have a condition specifying the 'width'.

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you're looking for? Simply use the `sort` function to put in order.

```
vector <- runif(10, min=0, max=101)
n <- 5
i <- sort(sample(seq_along(vector),n))
vector[i]
```

Answer (score 2):

One option is to use the `createDataPartition()` function from the [caret package](https://topepo.github.io/caret/data-splitting.html), e.g.

```
library(caret)
vector <- runif(10, min=0, max=101)
vector
#>[1] 49.12759 37.39169 99.31837 39.22023 23.15373 62.95305 13.79056 97.71442
#>[9] 52.02225 16.47010

sampling_index <- createDataPartition(y = vector, times = 1,
                                      p = 0.3, list = FALSE)
vector[sampling_index]
#>[1] 49.12759 39.22023 23.15373 97.71442
```

Comment: Thanks @jared_mamrot. As I have said to the rest that have nicely proposed a solution, I forgot to include an extra condition for creating the vector. I apologize. I have just included it. Do you know how to create the vector considering also that I do not want to select values very close to each other? Additionally, I wanted to ask you if you could explain what means the arguments in the function `createeDataPartition`.

Answer (score 1):

Try `sample` like

```
vector[sort(sample(length(vector),4))]
```

or

```
vector[head(which(sample(c(TRUE,FALSE),length(vector),replace = TRUE)),4)]
```

---

**Update**

If you have constraints regarding the minimum spacing between random indices, you can try the code below:

- non-optimized method

```
f1 <- function(vec,n, min_spacing = 4) {
  idx <- seq_along(vec)
  repeat {
    k <- sort(sample(idx,n))
    if (all(diff(k)>=min_spacing)) break
  }
  vec[k]
}
```

- optimized method

```
f2 <- function(vec, n, min_spacing = 4) {
  u <- unname(tapply(vec, ceiling(seq_along(vec) / min_spacing), sample, size = 1))
  head(u[seq(1, length(u), by = 2)], n)
}
```

Comment: Thanks @ThomaslsCoding. I forgot to include an extra condition for creating the vector. I apologize. I have just included it. Do you know how to create the vector considering also that I do not want to select values very close to each other?